# Can XBMC play Blu-Ray disks?

Tags: xbmc, blu-ray

Can XBMC play Blu-Ray disks without other steps (e.g. manually decrypting it - if I buy a Blu-ray movie, can it be played out of the box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about XBMC, but it looks like the bluray comes as a plugin:
http://lifehacker.com/5621471/how-to-enable-blu+ray-playback-in-xbmc

Comment: There is a quote in that article... "It certainly isn't ideal, but it's pretty remarkable how close it is to regular playback." That is not good. Until xbmc has a better answer for playing blu-rays, i will just stick with powerdvd. =(